# radial basis function (RBF) kernel

Tags: svm

Suppose we use the following radial basis function (RBF) kernel: K(xi; xj) =
exp(− 1 2 kxi − xjk2), which has some implicit unknown mapping φ(x).
• Prove that the mapping φ(x) corresponding to RBF kernel has infinite dimensions.
• Prove that for any two input examples xi and xj, the squared Euclidean distance of their
corresponding points in the higher-dimensional space defined by φ is less than 2, i.e.,
kφ(xi) − φ(xj)k2 ≤ 2.

Comment: There's putting your homework on Stack Overflow, and then there's this... You haven't even written around the question; you have literally just copied and pasted the question...

Comment: Not really a question about programming.